# Given graph of the function $f(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ What is the $x$ value at the local minimum point?

Tags: calculus, functions, maxima-minima

This is a problem from a timed exam, so I prefer approaches that lead to answer quickly.

> Graph of the function $f(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ is as follow. What is the
> $x$ value at the local minimum point?
>
> $1)\frac12\qquad\qquad2)2\qquad\qquad3)\frac32\qquad\qquad4)3$
>
> [image]

Here is my approach,

Suppose we have minima at $x_0$. We have,$$f(0)=4\Rightarrow c=4$$

$$f'(x)=3x^2+2ax+b\qquad\text{Since $f'(0)=0\rightarrow b=0$}$$Hence $f'(x)=x(3x+2a)$, So $x_0=-\frac{2a}3$. We have $f(x)=x^3+ax^2+4$. $$f(-\frac{2a}3)=0\Rightarrow -\frac{8a^3}{27}+\frac{4a^3}9+4=0\Rightarrow a=-3$$
Finally $x_0=\frac{-2a}3=2$.

---

Although one can get the answer with this approach in one or two minutes, I'm looking for quicker ways to solve the problem. Actually, first time I tried to solve the problem, I noticed that we can write $f(x)=(x+m)(x-n)^2$ where $m,n\in \mathbb{R}^+$. According to graph of function and noting that $f(0)=mn^2=4$, I can guess it the function is $f(x)=(x+1)(x-2)^2$. But assuming I'm in the exam, at this point should I quickly mark the answer and go to the next question or this approach is unreliable and I got the correct answer with a bit of luck?!

Comment: I am confused by the choices given.  Without any Math, the value of the local minimum is the **height** of the the graph at the place where the graph makes a $\color{red}{\text{U}}$ shape.  This is clearly the $x$-axis.  So, the value of the local minimum is : $f(x) = 0.$  It seems as if the question really intends to be asking for the $x$ coordinate of the point where the $\color{red}{\text{U}}$ shape touches the $x$-axis.  Besides that, I think that your analysis nailed how I would approach the problem.

Comment: It depends if the diagram is to scale, which it is normally acceptable to assume unless you see the phrase "diagram not to scale". In which case you could justify knowing the roots as $x_1=-1$ and $x_{2,3}=2$ and using the second method listed

Comment: @user2661923 I agree, the question should really say "what is the $x$ value at the local minimum point"

Comment: @user2661923 Sorry it was my mistake in translating. English is not my first language! (edited now).

Comment: I think your first method is quick enough. It is a very good approach, at least, to me. In a exam, we need both speed and correcteness. The first is reassuring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the shape of the graph you have two roots, call them $p$ for the single on the left and $q$ for the double root on the right, so the equation can be factorised as $(x-p)(x-q)^2=0$. This results in
$$
x^3-(p+2q)x^2+(2pq+q^2)x-pq^2=0
$$
The intercept gives us $-pq^2=4$ and the local maximum at $x=0$ gives us $2pq+q^2=0$ which gives us $q=-2p$, thus $p=-1$ and $q=2$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $s$ and $t$ denote the $x$-intercepts.

Then

$$ f(x)=(x-s)(x-t)^2 $$

Since we know $f(0)=4$ that gives $-st^2=4$ so $s=-\frac{4}{t^2}$

Next, we have

$$f^\prime(x)=(x-t)^2+2(x-s)(x-t)$$

Since $f^\prime(0)=0$ we have $t^2+2st=0$. Since we already have $s=-\frac{4}{t^2}$ we substitute to get $t^3-8=0$ giving $t=2$.

Notice that all you really need from the equation given for $f(x)$ is the fact that the leading coefficient of the polynomial is $1$. Everything else is given by the graph of $f$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that a cubic function has critical points at $x = r$ and $x = s$.  IOW, its derivative is zero at these points.  Then

$$f'(x) = k(x - r)(x - s)$$
$$f'(x) = k(x^2 - (r+s)x + rs)$$
$$f(x) = k(\frac{1}{3}x^3 - \frac{1}{2}(r + s)x^2 + rsx) + c$$

But you're given that the $x^3$ coefficient is 1, so $k = 3$.

$$f(x) = x^3 - \frac{3}{2}(r + s)x^2 + 3rsx + c$$

You're also given $r = 0$ and $c = 4$ at the other local extremum, so:

$$f(x) = x^3 - \frac{3}{2}sx^2 + 4$$

But at this local minimum point, $x = s$ and $f(x) = 0$, so:

$$x^3 - \frac{3}{2}x^3 + 4 = 0$$
$$-\frac{1}{2}x^3 = -4$$
$$x^3 = 8$$
$$x = 2$$

Answer (score 1):

Not a great deal faster, but you could also use the fact that the local extrema in the cubic function are symmetric about its inflection point, given by $ \ f''(x) \ = \ 6x +  2a \ = \ 0 $  $ \Rightarrow \ x_{infl} \ = \ -\frac{a}{3} \ \ . $  Since the local maximum is on the $ \ y-$axis (if the diagram is to be at all trusted), then the local minimum is at $ \ x_{min} \ = \ -\frac{2a}{3} \ \ . $  The function value at the inflection point is $ \ f\left(-\frac{a}{3} \right) \ = \ -\frac{a^3}{27} + \frac{a^3}{9} - \frac{ab}{3} + 4 \ = \ 2  \ \ . $  You will want to use your observation that $ \ f'(0) \ = \ 0 \ \Rightarrow \ b \ = \ 0 \ \ , $ so we have $ \ \frac{2·a^3}{27} \ = \ -2 \ \Rightarrow \ a^3 \ = \ -27 $ $ \Rightarrow \  x_{min} \ = \ -\frac{2·[-3]}{3} \ = \ +2 \ \ . $

Your educated guess that $ \ x^3 - 3x^2 + 4 \ = \ (x + 1)·(x - 2)^2 \ $ is correct; acting on that during the exam depends on how much of a gambler you are:  Viete tells you that $ \ c \ = \ 4 \ = \ -r·s^2 \ \ , $ so $ \ r \ = \ -1 \ \ , \ \ s \ = \ +2 \ $ would be worth the risk if you're desperate for time...

**ADDENDUM:**  It might also be noted that once you see that $ \ c \ = \ 4 \ \ , $ the Rational Zeroes Theorem lets you "reject" choices (3) and (4) (now... does $ \ \frac{1}{2} \ $ seems plausible...?).

Answer (score 1):

It may be a little faster to use the symmetry about the inflection point. Say the inflection point is at $(h,2)$, so $$f(x)=\left.x(x^2-v^2)\right\rvert_{\text{shifted}}=(x-h)\left((x-h)^2-v^2\right)+2$$

$f(0)=4$, so $$-h\left(h^2-v^2\right)=2\tag{!}$$

And
$$f'(x)=3(x-h)^2-v^2$$
and then $f'(0)=0$, so
$$3h^2-v^2=0$$

Now you know $v^2=3h^2$, so return to (!):

$$-h\left(-2h^2\right)=2$$

This implies $h=1$. So the positive root of $f$ is at $x=2h=2$.